# Combating Multicollinearity in Multivariate Granger Causality

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multicollinearity, granger-causality

Let's say that I have a variable $X_1$ that Granger-Causes a variable $Y$. For simplicity, assume only 1 lag. Now, let's say I have two more variables $X_2$ and $X_3$ which happen to be exact copies of $X_1$ (I don't know that prior to starting the analysis). I would like to perform multivariate analysis to see which of the three $X$ variables Granger-Cause $Y$. Here is my current understanding of the two possible analysis procedures and their results:

1. Perform pairwise Granger Causality analysis between $X_i$ and $Y$ for each $i \in \{1,2,3\}$. This analysis will conclude that each $X_i$ individually Granger-causes $Y$
2. Perform multivariate Granger Causality analysis, namely, constructing a linear model of $Y$ using all $X_i$ simultaneously, then testing if each coefficient is different from zero. To the best of my understanding, this analysis will conclude that none of the variables $X_i$ Granger-causes $Y$, because neither of $X_i$ improves the knowledge about $Y$ given the other two.

**Questions**:

1. Is my understanding of Granger Causality application to this toy example correct? If not, please elaborate
2. Are there extensions of Multivariate Granger Causality that can adequately deal with multicollinearity? I guess you would agree that neither of the following statements exhaustively illustrates the nature of the relationship between these variables.

   - "*All of $X_i$ Granger-Cause $Y$*"
   - "*None of $X_i$ Granger-Cause $Y$*"
   - *"Randomly-selected one of $X_i$'s Granger-Causes $Y$, about the rest the algorithm is undecided"*

**Edit**: Based on discussion, the two following criteria are important for the desired metric

1. The metric must be robust - coefficients are not allowed to jump chaotically due to small perturbations in data or fitting algorithm
2. The metric must attempt to communicate its certainty about each individual coefficient in some way. Can the model still achieve best fit if this coefficient is set to 0?

Comment: This seems like an instance of multicollinearity, in which case the linear model from 2 could not be fitted with all three predictors, so your software would (basically arbitrarily) drop two of these and then perform the test from 1.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks, I've learned a new word (multicollinearity, I used an almost synonymous word redundancy in the text). So, how does one combat multicollinearity in Multivariate Granger Causality analysis?

Comment: You can't really combat it, because linear regression coefficients (which is what the Granger test is based on) say what happens when its regressor changes by one unit when all the others are held constant. When regressors are multicollinear you can't use the data to answer that question because any change in one regressor is *always* accompanied by a proportional change in the multicollinear regressor. Basically, you ask the regression to explain changes in the dependent variable by the same thing twice (or three times here, with two exact copies).

Comment: That's why I ask for extensions. Something that exceeds naive regression. Surely it is possible to compute 2 numbers: 1) amount of explained variance of this predictor in the absence of other predictors 2) amount of explained variance of this predictor after all other predictors are fitted to the target (its unique contribution), and then proceed to make some conclusions based on the two numbers. Has a similar procedure been formalized?

Comment: Well, yes, look for procedures like ridge regression that work in the presence of collinearity. I still do not see the appeal of a Granger test that tests if a variable marginally improves prediction of a dependent variable in the presence of other variables, including, basically, itself (which is how I view the "exact copy"), though.

Comment: I should clarify the application. I work in neuroscience. In this field, one of the approaches to understanding the brain is so called functional connections (FC) - directed links between brain areas, computed solely based on the observation of these areas as time-dependent variables. FC can be computed via cross-correlation, GC or more sophisticated metrics. Brain areas are multi-collinear to some extent, and multicollinearity structure may change over time. The important question in FC is robustness - individual connections may not depend on small perturbations in fitting algorithm.

Comment: Is ridge regression robust? As in, are the coefficients guaranteed to be stable under small perturbations of data?

Comment: My hunch would be no less than linear regression (which, being based on quadratic loss, isn't particularly robust) given that it performs some shrinkage to zero. But I am not sure. Also, statistical inference (like a GC test) based on a biased estimator like ridge will be more difficult.